# Hive output to xlsx

Tags: hive

I am not able to open an `.xlsx` file. Is this the correct way to output the result to an `.xlsx` file?

```
hive -f hiveScript.hql > output.xlsx
```

Answer (score 2):

hive -S -f hiveScript.hql > output.xls

This will work

Comment: I am curious to know what does -S do?

Comment: It is used for running your query in silent mode, while running from hive cli. With out -S also you can get expected results in your case.

Comment: How is this different than what @Absout_Red answered 2 hours before you (besides silent mode, which has nothing to do with OP question)?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 differene is xls & xlsx. I already mentioned silent mode won't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to create an Excel (.xlsx) file directly from hive. You could output you queries content to an older version of Excel (.xls) by the answers given above and it would open in Excel properly (with an initial warning in latest versions of Office) but in essence it is just a text file with .xls extension. If you open this file with any text editor you would see the contents of the query output.

Take any .xlsx file on your system and open it with a text editor and see what you get. It will be all junk characters since that is not a simple text file.

Having said that there are many programming languages that allow you to convert/read a text file and create xlsx. Since no information is provided/requested on this I will not go into details. However, you may use Pandas in Python to create excels.

Answer (score 0):

output csv or tsv file, and I used Python to do converting (pandas library)

Answer (score -1):

I am away from my setup right now so really cannot test this. But you can give this a try in your hive shell:

`hive -f hiveScript.hql >> output.xls`

Comment: The OP asks for the "correct way to **output** the result to a .xlsx file" rather than _exporting_ the result of the query to a.xlsx file. There is a subtle but significant difference in the two!

Anyways..what is the expectation for _rightly_ directing the output to a given **.xls** file from the terminal?  Even if bells and whistles were expected, it wasn't specified in the OP and I am _pretty sure_ they weren't.